# flutter firebaseauth signout() not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am using the firebase auth signout method but it doesnt seem to be working properly. when i click on the logout button, it is supposed to log the current user out. however, after doing so, the console does not indicate that the firebase auth signout method is actually working, none!

the app has a sysmte where if the user is online then they will always be redirected to the home page upon opening the app unless they log out from the app (which they will be redirected to the login page). and the app always redirects me to the home page when opening the app, hence it is clear that the firebase auth signout method is not working even after i hit the logout button

this is my logout method and it is in the `Authentication` class

```
FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth();

logOut() async {
    return await _auth.signOut();
}
```

this is the callback and the `logOutCurrentUser` function is called when i click the logout button

```
Authentication authentication = Authentication();
  
  logOutCurrentUser(BuildContext context) {
    try {
      authentication.logOut();
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginSignupToggle(true)), (route) => false);
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

all in all, it seems like `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` is still not null even after i hit the logout button which i expect it to be null after logging out

i have tried searching for an answer as much as i could but nothing seems to work for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Signout a user in Flutter with Firebase authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079459/how-to-signout-a-user-in-flutter-with-firebase-authentication)

Comment: no it doesnt wokr for me, i updated my question can you please have a look once more?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your sign-out is aborted because you're not waiting for it to finish. Since your `logOut` is `async` you need to use `await` when calling it:

```
await authentication.logOut();
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginSignupToggle(true)), (route) => false);
```