# is there any way to pop all screens in flutter app by one click without logging the user out?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I want the user to be able to exit the app by clicking the phone back button one time (and then he gets a warning message).

but all I found is the option to call to `exit(0)`, but this is logging the user out.

I am using firebase & flutter.

Also, when pressing the back button when I'm in the home_page (which appears after logging), I get the login view again instead of exiting the app.
How can I prevent that (because I want the user to stay logged in)

these is the code in my main.dart build() :

```
return StreamProvider<User?>.value(
  value: logic.listenToUserAuth(),
  initialData: null, //user signed out
  child: MaterialApp(
    //initialRoute: '/login',
    //routes: this.routes,
    // passing the change in stream to child widgets
    home: MainWrapper(routes: this.routes,),
  ),
```

these is the code from MainWrapper build() , that determines which view to show to the user, depends if he is logged in or not, but it does not work.. the user always gets the '/login' view :

```
final user = Provider.of<User?>(context);
String initRout = "/login";
// the user logged in
if(user != null) {
  initRout = "/home_page.dart";
}
return MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: initRout,
  routes: routes,
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the back button issues, this libray will solve your problem
https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor

To sign out user, use this method on button clicks or after doing some logic

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
```

To persist user auth using flutter and firebase, refer to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45084649/11838875

Comment: i want the opposite, the user to stay logged in to the app even when it is closed. and as to the library-can you be more specific about which is the right method for my case? i need to pop all screens of the app

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, the [Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package solved everything, use [Get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package, and then use Get.offAll("spacify the screen which should be last in the stack"); and you're done