# User info getting saved even after logout. Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to sign a user out and sign a new user in. I am not able to do that. The information of previous user is somehow being saved, I can't deduce how. Any idea what should I do? I followed the answer in this post : [How to Signout a user in Flutter with Firebase authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45079459/how-to-signout-a-user-in-flutter-with-firebase-authentication)
added await keyword but its still not quite working
This is the code to it. I am going to Log in page but after login previous users information is being shown to this new user

```
Future<void> signOut(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      await firebaseObject.signOut().then((value) {
        Timer(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, RoutesName.login);
        });
        Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("Logged out successfully", context,
            color: Constants.blueColor);
      });
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {}
}
```

Comment: can you add the code from your ``signOut`` method

Comment: this is the whole sign out code. I think what might have confused you is the variable firebaseObject. Its actually Firebase.instance. i used variable instead. This  is the sign out code only

Comment: actually yes. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65039130/5882307